Two dimensional integral of log function $\log(z-w)$
I want to solve the following two-dimensional integral in a disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin
$$
I(w,\bar{w}) = \int_D \log(z - w) d^2 z\,,\quad D = \{(x,y)|x^2+y^2 < R\}\,,\,R > |w|
$$
where $d^2z = dx dy$, $w$ is a complex number and we specify the branch cut of the integrand as $\log z = \log |z| + i\theta$, $\theta \in[-\pi,\pi]$. With this choice of branch cut $I(w,\bar{w})$ should be real when $w \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $I(0,0) = \frac{\pi}{2} R^2 (2\log R - 1)$.
Here is my attempt. Recall the identity
$$
\partial_{\bar{w}} \frac{1}{w} = \pi \delta^{(2)}(w)
$$
we have
$$
\partial_{\bar{w}}\partial_w I(w,\bar{w}) = \pi \int_D \delta^{(2)}(z - w) d^2 z = \pi
$$
Therefore, the original integral is
$$
I(w,\bar{w}) = \pi \bar{w} w + C_1 w + C_2 \bar{w} + \frac{\pi}{2} R^2 (2\log R - 1)
$$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are still undetermined.
Set aside the values of $C_1$ and $C_2$. I think this approach is wrong. For example, we can apply a similar logic to compute the real part of the integral
$$
\text{Re} I(w,\bar{w}) = \int_D \log|z - w| d^2 z
$$
Using the fact that $\nabla^2 \log|z - w| = 2\pi \delta^{(2)}(z-w)$, we get
$$
\text{Re} I(w,\bar{w}) = \frac{\pi}{2} \bar{w} w + \frac{\pi}{2} R^2 (2\log R - 1)
$$
This result has also been discussed in this related post.
I am curious what will be the correct way to approach this integral. Any comments are welcome.
